# Solving a system of PDE by fixed point Gauss-seidel iteration method

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I have the following system of PDE
$$
u-u_0=\operatorname{div}\left(\frac{\nabla u-w}{|\nabla u-w|}\right) \tag 1
$$
$$
\frac{w-\nabla u}{|w-\nabla u|} = \operatorname{div}\left(\frac{\nabla w}{|\nabla w|}\right) \tag 2
$$
where $u_0$ is the given data and the domain of PDEs are an unit square $Q$ in $\mathbb R^2$. Function $u$: $Q\to \mathbb R$ and $w$: $Q\to\mathbb R^2$.

Let's ignore about the regularity and singularity for now. From equation $(1)$ I have 
$$
u=u_0+\operatorname{div}\left(\frac{\nabla u-w}{|\nabla u-w|}\right)
$$
and from $(2)$ I have
$$
w=\operatorname{div}\left(\frac{\nabla w}{|\nabla w|}\right)\cdot|w-\nabla u|+\nabla u \tag 3
$$
Then I propose to use fixed point Gauss-seidel iteration method by
$$
u^{n+1}=u_0+\operatorname{div}\left(\frac{\nabla u^n-w^n}{|\nabla u^n-w^n|}\right) \tag 4
$$
$$
w^{n+1}=\operatorname{div}\left(\frac{\nabla w^n}{|\nabla w^n|}\right)\cdot|w^n-\nabla u^{n+1}|+\nabla u^{n+1}
$$
I know there are might some minor error need to be fixed, but I am wondering is my idea make sense? One thing I am particular worry is that I have $w$ on the both hand of equation $(4)$.

And, the matlab simulation is divergence...

Any suggestions are really welcome!

Comment: Just a small comment: to make it "Gauss-Seidel", you might use $u^{n+1}$ on the second line of (4) instead of $u^n$.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel of course. This is actually what I am using. But my result is still diverge to $+\infty$. Is there any fatal mistake here?